# Get WooCommerce Product Attribute label name

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

Variable/variations in woocommerce products.

I can do this to get the attribute value from pa_size: `<?php echo $product_variation->get_attributes()['pa_size']; ?>` which is somewhere in `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product&page=product_attributes`.

But how do I get the `pa_size` label (in this case: 'Size')? Have tried to fetch everything based on post_type, page and then the "term_group". But that won't work. I can see that this usually is visible per default, but this is a custom solution. Also in https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.8.0/templates/single-product/product-attributes.php I can't see where they print the actual label, only the "Attribute child label and value". But not actual parent (pa_size => Size).

Have googled like a maniac for hours now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the label name of a WooCommerce product attribute you will use one of the 2 following ways:

1) Using Woocommerce [`wc_attribute_label()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-attribute-functions.php#L179-L212) dedicated function:

```
$taxonomy   = 'pa_size';
$label_name = wc_attribute_label( $taxonomy );
```

2) Using wordPress [`get_taxonomy()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_taxonomy/) function:

```
$taxonomy   = 'pa_size';
$label_name = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you already know the taxonomy itself `pa_size`.

All product attributes are just taxonomies, with the `pa_` prefix beforehand.

Then you will be able to print them using [`get_term_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/)

it should look something like this:

```php
<?php
$term = get_term_by('slug', $product_variation->get_attributes()['pa_size'], 'pa_size');
echo $term->name;
?>
```

Comment: Maybe this answer is slightly less simple or straightforward than the accepted answer, but it bears greater potential because one could readily access the term object for whatever other related purposes.